# Email already exist with Jquery validator plugin in codeigniter is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validator plugin in Codeigniter and I want to check the email field whether given email already exists or not. I have done all the necessary according to the instruction provided in the Jquery validator documentation but it's not working properly in Codeigniter. Can someone assist me with this problem?

```js
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#signupFrm").validate({
            rules: {
                customer_contactNumber: {
                    required: true,
                    digits: true,
                    minlength: 10,
                    maxlength:14
                },
                customer_email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    remote: {
                        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/account/register_email_exists",
                        type: "post",
                    }
                },
            },
            messages: {
                customer_contactNumber:{
                    required: "Please enter your Contact Number",
                    minlength: "Contact number should not be lesser than 10 digits",
                    maxlength: "Contact number should not be higher than 14 digits",
                    digits: "Please enter numbers Only"
                },
                customer_email:{
                    required: "Please enter your email",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email",
                    remote: "Email already exist"
                },
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

sign up form

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="customer_email" name="customer_email">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
</div>
```

Controller

```
function register_email_exists()
{
    if (array_key_exists('customer_email',$_POST))
    {
        $email=$_POST["customer_email"];

        $this->load->model("Email_auth");

        $this->Email_auth->verifyEmailExist($email);

        if ($this->Email_auth->verifyEmailExist($email) == TRUE)
        {
            echo json_encode("FALSE");
        }
        else
        {
            echo json_encode("TRUE");
        }
    }
}
```

Email_auth.php

```
<?php

class Email_auth extends CI_Model {

    function verifyEmailExist($email) 
    {
        $this->db->select('customer_id');

        $this->db->where(array("customer_email" => $email));

        $query=$this->db->get('tbl_customer');

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you load `Email_auth` but you use `Admin_auth` ?

Comment: Would have been great for you to have taken the time to properly format your code for readability, which helps others to help you.  Also, don't use the "snippets" feature unless it's HTML/CSS/JavaScript that can run within this window.  The panes are clearly labeled as such, so obviously you should not put PHP in there.

Comment: "its not working properly" isn't a valid problem statement. what isn't working properly? have you checked the console? have you checked the network pane of dev tools to see what the request is returning?

Comment: @Sparky sorry, sure I'll be more careful next time. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that your remote CodeIgniter PHP function is properly querying your database.

1. You do **not** need the `data` parameter at all unless you want to send information in addition to the field.  By default, the value of the field is already sent.

   REMOVE all of this:

   ```
   data:{
       customer_email: function() { 
           return $("#customer_email").val();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Your boolean needs to be in quotation marks.  In the case of `"true"` and `"false"`, it works with and without the `json_encode()`.  However, if you want to send a message string instead of `"false"`, the `json_encode()` is mandatory.

   `echo json_encode("true");`

   OR `echo "true";`
3. Finally, if you have CSRF protection enabled within CodeIgniter, then you MUST send the value of the hidden token within your `data` parameter.  Again, you will NOT send the value of the `customer_email` field as this is being sent already by default.  (Replace below  `csrftoken` with the actual `name` of your token.)

   ```
   data: {
       csrftoken: function() {
           return $('input[name="csrftoken"]').val();
       }
   }
   ```